# onPostExecute() of AsyncTask never get called in AndroidTestCase

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-intent, android-asynctask

I am writing a very simple unit test case for my Android project, the test case simplely execute a `AsyncTask` which does network operation in background. I am extending `AndroidTestCase` class for my test case:

```
public class MyTest extends AndroidTestCase{
  //use CountDownLatch to perform wait-notify behavior
  private CountDownLatch signal;
  @Override
  public void setUp() throws Exception{
     super.setUp();
     //I use CountDownLatch to perform wait-notify behaviour
     signal = new CountDownLatch(1); 
  }

  @Override
  public void runTest() throws Exception{
        String params = "some params";
        //MyAsyncTask does the networking tasks
        new MyAsyncTask().execute(params);

       //wait until MyAsyncTask is done
       try {
        signal.await();
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    
  }

  private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
        
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
          //Do networking task e.g. access a remote database
     }
     
     @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        super.onPostExecute(result);
            //this never get called when run this test case, why?
           Log.i("Debug","post execute");       
           signal.countDown();
    }
  }
}
```

As you see above, I am using [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) to perform **wait-notify** behavior.

After `MyAsicTask` starts, I invoke `signal.await()` to **wait** for `MyAsyncTask` to finish.

In `onPostExecute()` callback of `MyAsyncTask`, I call `signal.countDown()` to **notify** that the task is done.

But when I run this test case, the `onPostExecute` is never called, **why & how to fix it?**

**========Update==========**

After I added `Thread.sleep(30*1000)` as the last line in `runTest()`, I can see more logs from network operations. It proves that the `teardown()` is invoked before my network operation finished. I did nothing in tearDown(), android test framework. invokes it automatically.

Seems my **wait-notify** by using `CountDownLatch` is not working... Why?

Comment: Any exception in doInBackground?

Comment: there might be something going wrong in `doInBackground` and hence `onPostExecute` isn't getting the call..

Comment: @d3m0li5h3r Unless doInbackground() crashes and cancels the Async Task its not possible that onPostExecute() will not get execute.

Comment: @Brontok.. thats exactly what I meant.. Either he's getting an Exception in `doInBackground` or the task has been cancelled via a call to `cancel()` method.

Comment: Hi, all, there is no exception in doInBackgroud(), the tearDown() is called when networking operation is on going..... My purpose to use CountDownLatch is to avoid this situation, but it still happens, why?

Comment: Are you sure the AsyncTask is started on the main thread? Im having the same problem and this seams to be the reason for the problem in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Since I had the same problem... here's what solvede it for me.
Instead of letting the class extend AndroidTestCase I let it extend InstrumentationTestCase.

Then i start the asyncTask like this:

```
runTestOnUiThread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            startAsyncTask();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your network operation is very time consuming process so it takes so long time that why its can not called  onPostExecute() method.

Comment: Because Android does not allow the network operations to be in the main thread (UI thread), I have to put it in a background thread.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that your doInBackground method is not the reason this problem. Try this sample task. And share the log result please.

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Log.i("Debug", "onPreExecute");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        Log.i("Debug", "doInBackground");
        return "operation finished";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Log.i("Debug", "onPostExecute");
        signal.countDown();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        super.onCancelled();
        Log.i("Debug", "onCancelled");
    }
}
```

**Edit:** I wondered that there may be a problem while working with `AndroidTestCase`s and `AsyncTask`s. I just copied your code to my project and tested it with an `AsyncTask`(see my task above). On every launch after `doInBackground`, `onPostExecute` method is called successfully. I simulated a long running task with sleep 2 minutes, and that also entered to `onPostExecute` method. And `tearDown` method invoked after `onPostExecute`.

So, your problem here is probably a loop inside your `doInBackground` method. Or it is cancelled somehow and task's `onCancelled` method invoked.

Answer (score 0):

The `onPostExecute()` is supposed to be run in the caller thread of `execute()`. If that thread becomes suspended by calling something like `signal.await()`, the `onPostExecute()` won't be able to run. So you cannot have `signal.await()` after calling `execute()`.